# Copying Classes with Dynamic Memory

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deep copy vs Shallow Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657810/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy)
>   [What is the difference between overloading operator= and overloading the copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418503/what-is-the-difference-between-overloading-operator-and-overloading-the-copy-co)

I see two ways of copying a class:

1. Copy Constructor
2. operator=

My question is, which one should make a new copy of dynamically allocated memory (2 classes with the same data and 2 instances of dynamic memory) and which should simply move the class to a new memory location (one class with the same dynamically allocated memory but the class is in a different place)?

Comment: Both must provide this functionality

Comment: there are two different operations and i need to distinguish which one is desired

Comment: @user1204406 the only sane way to distinguish between a copy and a move is to use copy and move constructors and copy and move assignment operators, with rvalue references from C++11.

Comment: The only way you can copy a class is by using copy/paste in your editor. Maybe you mean "copy an object"?

Comment: Credit goes to R. Martinho Fernandes for answering the question out of the eight responses

Comment: This question and its closure are being discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152792/

Comment: @andrey, other close voters: can you review the meta question Bart linked to and see if you still think this is a dupe?

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor creates a new object and initializes its state based on an existing object:

```
A x(y); // x is now in the same state as y
```

An assignment operator takes an existing object and changes its state to match another existing object:

```
A x; // x is in the default state
x = y; // x is now in the same state as y
```

Whatever decisions you make about the state should apply equally to both.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement both because you can declare variable through copy constructor. You can assign to variable. For example:

```
Class a; //some heap allocations inside
Class b(a); //must be valid
Class c = a; //must be valid too
```

And dont forget about destructor. Simple way is achieve copy and assign operator is to use copy when assign then swap(copy&swap). [Copy & swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) and [Rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)